# Multilanguage site with two domains

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to make the same site in two languages, spanish and english. After test a pair of plugins and see which options exists looking at some technical blogs, I think the better is to make two blog with native languages in different domains.

So now I have one site running in spanish (not full but near ready), and I need to translate to english. Migrate content is hard but I think I can do it. The problem for me is how to display flags, and redirect to target site. ¿How can I do this?

I´ve seen Zanto plugin but I don´t know if it suits my needs.

Any comment or advise is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered a very similar question.

Instead of having 2 separate websites, it's far easier to install a translation plugin. The plugin will basically add extra fields or tabs in edit mode. For example, if you are editing a page titled "Home", you will have a field for the English page title and then a field for the Spanish page title. The same goes for the description field.

Configuration is very easy and once you've selected the languages you need, the plugin will automatically add these fields to edit mode.

There are 2 very good WordPress translation plugins that I use on a regular basis.

WPML (http://wpml.org) is my favourite. The only downside is that you have to pay a yearly license. If you're looking for a free plugin, check out: [QTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/).

Both plugins allow you to have sub domains (en.yoursite.com) or language folders (yoursite.com/en).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Squideyes for your suggestion, but I´m not interested in using translation plugins, neither subdomains or subfolders. I only need an icon with a flag and the ability to redirect to each site.

Comment: No worries. Am I correct in thinking that you will have 2 separate websites each running a different WordPress installation? I.e. yoursite.es (Spanish) and yoursite.co.uk (English)?

Comment: Yes, that is. I know it´s more work but after see different options I think is better.

Comment: So you'd need to introduce a 3rd domain (yoursite.com) for the re-direction, correct? The translation plugins I mentioned can auto detect the visitors language and redirect them to a sub domain or language folder. In addition you'll have the ability to easily list flags. I don't see the benefit in having completely different websites. It's far easier to manage content with a language plugin. By having 2 websites, you're opening yourself up to more work in terms of content management, WP maintenance and development for the redirect.

Comment: Thanks again! I´ll try QTranslate to see if works as I need.

Comment: No worries :) Let me know how you get on.